# How to Sort object by alphabet order for UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nsmutablearray, nsobject

I want to sort objects that i created & stored in `NSMutableArray` in `AppDelegate.m`.
  Stations is `NSObject` Class

I want to show station names in another `UIViewController` in alphabet order(in `UITableViewCell`) & when i click on them i want to pass the object that contains station name,latitude,longitude to next `UIViewController`

Currently i have extracted station name from stationList(Global `NSMutableArray`) to another NSMutableArray on `UIViewController`s Cell & sorted it via

```
[sortedArray sortUsingSelector:@selector(localizedCaseInsensitiveCompare:)];
```

but when didSelectRowAtIndexPath is being called i have to get this name from cell & search it in the stationList array to pass lat,long which is not good i think.

stationList Array Log(It has 100 objects):-

```
<__NSArrayM 0x79a2f110>(
<Stations: 0x78743540>,
<Stations: 0x78743630>,
<Stations: 0x78743670>,
<Stations: 0x78743750>,
<Stations: 0x78743830>,
<Stations: 0x78743910>,
<Stations: 0x78743a10>,
<Stations: 0x78743af0>
}

 -(void)loadStations
{
    stationList = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"stations" ofType:@"txt"];
    NSString *content = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    //    NSLog(@"%@",content);

    NSArray *tempArr = [content componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];

    for (int i =0; i<[tempArr count]; i++)
    {
        NSString *rawData = [tempArr objectAtIndex:i];

        if (rawData !=nil)
        {
            Stations *newStation = [[Stations alloc]init];

            NSArray *data = [rawData componentsSeparatedByString:@"\t"];

            newStation.sId = i+1;
            newStation.name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[data objectAtIndex:0]];
            newStation.latitude = [[data objectAtIndex:1] doubleValue];
            newStation.longitude = [[data objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];

            [stationList addObject:newStation];
        }
    }
}
```

Suggest me good practice/way for this, or maybe use Dictionary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two solutions here:

1) you can retrieve object from your `stationList` based on `indexPath.row`

```
- (void) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    Stations* station = stationsList[indexPath.row];
    ...
}
```

2) you can create custom `UITableViewCell` and store referenced object there:

```
@interface StationCell : UITableVIewCell
    @property(weak) Stations* station;
@end

...

- (UITableViewCell*) tableView:(UITableVIew*)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
     StationCell* cell;

     // dequeue StationCell
     ...

    cell.station = stationList[indexPath.row]; 
}

...


- (void) tableView:(UITableView*)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath*)indexPath
{
    StationCell* cell = [tableView cellAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    Stations* station = cell.station;
    ...
}
```

I would choose between solutions based on complexity of data displayed in cell - using custom `UITableViewCell` gives oportunity to move configuration of cell from view controller to cell implementation.

**edit**

As far as sorting `stationsList`, you can use e.g.:

```
NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"name" ascending:YES];
stationsList = [stationsList sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
```

Comment: i want to show only name of station in the Cell & how do i sort station name by ascending according to your solution?

I want to add title for section according to number of stations name & shortcut list that comes by default in Contact App.

Comment: I've edited my post, hopefuly it aswers your question

Comment: sort this array in cellForRowAtIndexPath or in ViewdidLoad?

Comment: viewDidLoad. You want to have data sorted during entire user interaction.

Answer (score 1):

I would advise against sorting an array of station names separate from your array stationList. Instead I would suggest sorting your stationList (or a copy of it if you only want to change the oder in the table view and need to maintain some other ordering elsewhere)

There are methods like sortUsingComparator: that takes comparator block as a parameter. You write a block that compares 2 elements in your array, and the method uses that block to figure out the ordering of your objects and sort the array. In your case it would simply be a matter of writing a block that compares the name properties of 2 station objects.